# drop down menu not working, jQuery not loading

Tags: html

https://thelittlestschnauzer.github.io/module3_solution/

I have tried to get the html file to load the jQuery and I keep running into a brick wall. the drop down menu will not open when in the xs view. I click the navigation drop down icon and nothing happens.

Comment: WHat exactly are you trying to make as the drop down..the way it is setup looks like the whole top bar is the drop down.. or are you referring to the sidenav / mobile nav?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you do so. When asking a question, be [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and be sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are loading your scripts improperly. Move the jquery to the bottom and in order.

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping!! I had a silly period where it didn't belong!! What a rush when I deleted it and refreshed the code and boom my page worked!!! I'm new to the world of code but man I never want to stop! Thank you again for helping I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad it all worked out and welcome to the world where a period can make one go crazy for hours :P

Answer (score 0):

All your scripts have a 404(not found error) make sure you are linking them properly. Check the console.